# How to pass text parameter to stored function for `IN` operator

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I need obtain table names from schema, except some tables

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  func(unnecessary_tables TEXT)
returns void
as $$
begin
      EXECUTE 'SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables   
      WHERE 
      table_schema=''public''
      AND 
      table_name NOT IN( $1 )
      ' USING unnecessary_tables

      --here execute retrieved result, etc ...

end;
$$language plpgsql
```

Then call function

```
select func('table1'',''table2');
```

This not works and returns in result  `table1` and `table2` also.

Question is: How to pass text parameter to stored function, for `IN` operator ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `select func('table1, table2');`?

Comment: @Gabriel's  No, I am trying this also, but not works

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT func( '''table1'',''table2''');`? I think there was a problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass a text array in instead of text:

```
create or replace function func(unnecessary_tables text[])
returns void as $$
begin
    select table_name
    from information_schema.tables   
    where
        table_schema = 'public'
        and
        not(table_name = any($1))
    ;
end;
$$language plpgsql
```

Call it like:

```
select func(array['t1','t2']::text[]);
```

BTW the code above can be plain SQL in instead of PL/pgSQL

Comment: It can be enhanced by `VARIADIC` parameter - then you can call the function by `SELECT func('t1','t2')`

Answer (score 3):

To answer you exact question (How to pass to function text for `IN` operator) You need:

```
SELECT func( '''table1'',''table2''');
```

The reason is that table names must by string, so they need to by inside quotes. 
To make it works there is one change in code needed which I did't see at first:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  func(unnecessary_tables TEXT)
returns void
as $$
begin
      EXECUTE 'SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables   
      WHERE 
      table_schema=''public''
      AND 
      table_name NOT IN(' || unnecessary_tables || ')'; 

      --here execute retrieved result, etc ...

end;
$$language plpgsql
```

It's needed because `USING`is aware of types and don't just "paste" parameter in place of `$1`.

Comment: This works for you? Iam trying this also, but it was not working

Comment: Oh, I did't notice you use `EXECUTE ... USING ...`. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think none of above answers are correct.

```
select pg_typeof(table_name),table_name::text 
   from information_schema.tables   
   where table_schema = 'public';
```

It will return:

```
             pg_typeof             |        table_name
-----------------------------------+--------------------------
 information_schema.sql_identifier | parent_tree
```

from Which means at least the table_name should be cast to text.
Here is my solution:

```
create or replace function n_fnd_tbl(_other_tables text[])
returns table(__table_name text) as 
$$
begin
  return query EXECUTE format('
    select table_name::text
    from information_schema.tables   
    where table_schema = ''public''
    and table_name  <> ''%s''',_other_tables );
end
$$language plpgsql;
```

Then call it:

```
select * from n_fnd_tbl(array['tableb','tablea']::text[]);
```